# Force WagTail to ignore user's locale

Tags: wagtail

We've got a number of sites where the frontend is translated into different languages, but we would like Wagtail's CMS to remain in English. (Because we're seeing partial translations in Wagtail.)

Is there a way that we can force Wagtail to ignore the user's locale?

Answer (score 0):

Are you relying somehow on Django's internationalisation features to power front-end translations?

The primary language should be set to English by default, but perhaps you have the locale middleware class installed?

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...

    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)
```

if so you could try removing this.

See the [Wagtail docs I18N page.](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.4.3/advanced_topics/i18n/index.html?highlight=translat#id4) for more information.